# Heroku: Rails server works forever

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, thin

I ran the Rails application on Heroku. The problem: my application is turned off when no one for a while not in use, but as soon as the user enters - the server is started.
How do I make it work forever?

Rails, Thin web server.

My Procfile:

```
web: bundle exec rails server thin-p $ PORT
```

Comment: Are you just trying to get rid of the startup delay on the first request? Otherwise, this issue should never really matter to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pay money to Heroku. That's how. (Yes, that's how.)

Heroku will **idle** all applications with only one web dyno (i.e., the free tier) after detecting a reasonably short period of inactivity. [Reference.](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-idling)

Comment: You could also have a task or something that loads a page every 30 minutes or so, which would prevent it from idling.

Comment: You could. But you would have to host the task somewhere. And, depending on how much you care, you might want to set up high availability for the task server (or at least notifications and alerting on the task server, which may require a separate monitoring server).